# Check if a string has HTML in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net

I need a function to determine whether or not a string has HTML in it or not so that I can know whether I'm dealing with a plain-text format or HTML format.

It seems simple enough in C#, using HTMLAgilityPack.  Recursively go through the tree of nodes, and if any are an element node (or comment too) then we say "Yes, it's HTML"

```
public static class HTMLUtility
{
    public static bool ContainsHTMLElements(string text)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(text);

        bool foundHTML =  NodeContainsHTML(doc.DocumentNode);
        return foundHTML;
    }

    private static bool NodeContainsHTML(HtmlNode node)
    {
        return node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element
            || node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Comment
            || node.ChildNodes.Any(n => NodeContainsHTML(n));
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything?  Thanks!

Comment: Can `text` be just any HTML element, or is it supposed to be an entire HTML document?

Comment: It could be any text that may or may not have HTML inside of it.  If "text" has value "blah blah blah <div>  Hello world!  </div>", then then the function should return true

Comment: If so then for any _valid_ html it should be enough to check whether the first non-empty character is a `<`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had to do this exact thing before, your way is absolutely fine but I went for the other way round - checking if it was all text:

```
private static bool HtmlIsJustText(HtmlNode rootNode)
{
    return rootNode.Descendants().All(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text);
}
```

Then you have your public method as:

```
public static bool ContainsHTMLElements(string text)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(text);
    return !HtmlIsJustText(doc.DocumentNode);
}
```

I think that makes the code slightly more concise.

---

I'd argue that your class should really be called HtmlUtility as per [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter names, capitalizes the first character of each word (including acronyms over two letters in length), as shown in the following examples:
>
> - `PropertyDescriptor`
> - `HtmlTag`